# Simplest way to have trinidad depend on an alternate version of jruby-rack?

Tags: jruby, jrubyonrails, jruby-rack, trinidad-gem

The current Trinidad gem depends on jruby-rack 1.1.0 which has some errors being displayed in my development log for every single one of my assets

`/Users/bijan/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.3/gems/rack-1.4.5/lib/rack/utils.rb:399 warning: multiple values for a block parameter (2 for 1)`

This is an issue that has apparently been resolved in the current jruby-rack (1.2) master branch and I'd like to make trinidad depend on this.

Is there a way to do this from within my Gemfile? Or another simpler solution than forking the Trinidad gem and specifying a different version of jruby-rack (and wishing it works since it may not).

Comment: This problem is also driving me nuts.  Anyone got an answer?

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR - not really. You'll need to build one or both projects or get some help from the `jruby-rack` team by way of a release. See bottom for build steps.

---

The current Trinidad versions ([1.4.4](http://rubygems.org/gems/trinidad/versions/1.4.4) and 1.4.5B1 prerelease) use `jruby-rack` with optimistic versioning (`>= 1.1.10` and `>= 1.1.13`, respectively), so any dependency that satisfies this (say, 1.2.0) would take precedence without touching Trinidad.

Unfortunately, because of how the JAR is packaged, a `git:` or `github:` dependency will not work. You would need to [build the gem](https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack#building) yourself. This is not too bad -- you really just need Maven beyond a working JDK/JRuby setup.

Once `jruby-rack` is built/released with the changes, will be able to specify a workable version in your Gemfile (assuming it gets versioned 1.2.0):

```
gem 'jruby-rack', '~> 1.2.0'
gem 'trinidad'
```

Maybe the `jruby-rack` team could backport this specific change to the 1.1.13 maintenance line and push a 1.1.13.2 release if it doesn't introduce incompatibility. Or they may be willing to do a prerelease from master.

---

I haven't tested that things work properly for assets, but building and specifying the local version was relatively easy:

```
# Assuming mvn is on the path, JRuby is active, and you
# have gem install permissions:
git clone https://github.com/jruby/jruby-rack.git
cd jruby-rack
bundle install
bundle exec rake clean gem SKIP_SPECS=true
gem install --local target/jruby-rack-1.2.0.SNAPSHOT.gem
```

After this, you can use `gem 'jruby-rack', '~> 1.2.0.SNAPSHOT'` in your Gemfile to satisfy Trinidad and test whether your problem is resolved.